# Find the solution of the given initial value problem in explicit form.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the given initial value problem
in explicit form.

$$ \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=\frac{2x}{1+2y},\quad y(2)=0 $$

Can someone please help me with question. I separated the variables and got 
$y^2 + y = x^2 + C$ but I have no clue how to transform that into explicit form? I know explicit form has all the y on the left and t on the right, but I am not sure how to do that with the above problem...

Comment: solve the quadratic equation for $y$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{1+2y}$$

$$ (1+2y)dy = 2x \ dx$$

$$ y^2 + y = x^2 +c$$

To find an explicit solution, you need to factorise the following quadratic to obtain $y$:

$$y^2 + y -x^2-c = 0$$

Use the quadratic formula:

$$y = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$a = 1, \ b = 1, \ c= -(x^2+c)$

Once you've obtained an expression for $y$, you can then use the boundary condition to find the constant.

Comment: This was done by OP. The problem was to write it as $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$.

Comment: @mickep, that's exactly what I've explained in my answer-please read the answer well before commenting!

Comment: I read well, and I still have the same opinion.

Comment: OH ok. That makes sense now. Thank you so much John and everyone for the help!

Comment: @JohnClader, you're most welcome.

Comment: Now that it is edited, I agree!

Comment: A way to escape the horrible step $c=-(x^2+c)$ would be to identify $c=-4$ just before.

Answer (score 1):

$$y+y^2=x^2+C$$
use the boundary
$$0+0=4+C$$
$$C=-4$$
$$y^2+y-x^2+4=0$$
use the quadratic formula of the form
$$x^2+Ax+B=0$$
$$x=-0.5A\pm\sqrt{0.25A^2-B}$$
hence
$$y=-.5\pm\sqrt{0.25+x^2-4}$$
now we should check which solution satisfy the condition 
at $x=2$
$$y=-.5\pm\sqrt{0.25+4-4}$$
$$y=-.5\pm0.5$$
so the $+$ will satisfy the condition

hence
$$y=-.5+\sqrt{0.25+x^2-4}$$

Comment: To complete the solution, you should decide whether that $\pm$ is $+$ or $-$.  Only one of them satisfies $y(2) = 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember how to solve quadratic equations?  That's exactly what you have here.  Note also that you can use the initial condition $y(2)=0$ to eliminate the $C$, and also to tell you whether to use $+$ or $-$ in front of the square root.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit form of the solution would be finding an expression for $y$ as a function of the independent variable. In this case this would be $x$ and not $t$ as stated in your question.

This expression can be found by writing the implicit equation as $y^2+y-x^2-C=0$ and solve it as a quadratic equation, where $-x^2-C$ is the "constant" term of the quadratic equation. Depending on $x$ and $C$ this might have two possible solutions. The constant $C$ can be found by substituting $y$ with $0$ and $x$ with $2$ in to the implicit solution and solving for $C$.

If two solutions for $y(x)$ are found then re-applying the boundary value problem should eliminate one of the solutions.